# Javascript templates without additional frameworks/libraries

Tags: javascript, templates

I'm facing a development where we need to use JS templates, but without using any kind of frameworks or libraries such as Handlebars. I'm doing something like this:

```
var template = `
  <div>%text%</div>
`;

somediv.html(template.replace(/%test%/gi, 'some text'));
```

As this solution might work, it's not exactly what we want to maintain for the next months. Anyone here has faced a similar situation?

Comment: So… you *can* or you *can't* use libraries?!

Comment: @deceze Can't, I've edited my own question (too early, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

You can use es6 string template,

```
const text = 'some text';
const template = `<div>${text}</div>`;
```

then template will be `<div>some text</div>`